# IE11: Position absoluted DIV inside Flex container keeps out of the flow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, absolute

I have a display:flex container that contains an image and a div, the image have a 100% width and the div have to be centered horizontally and vertically in the container (with flex properties). In order for the image to show on top of the image i'm using position:absolute. The problem is that on IE11 the positioned absolute div keeps showing out of the flow.

This is how it looks on IE11:
[image]

This is how it have to look (Chrome):
[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container shop-service">
    <img class="img-container" src="/_ui/responsive/theme-lambda/services/image-services.jpg">
    <div class="shop-service-content">
        <div class="shop-service-img">
        <img alt="ecommerce" src="/_ui/responsive/theme-lambda/services/ecommerce.svg"></div>
        <h2>E-commerce</h2>
        <p class="col-md-12">Poderá fazer os seus pedidos a qualquer hora do dia, 365 días por ano, de forma
        segura, ágil e confidencial.</p> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Open-Catalogue/c/1">Comprar agora</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.shop-service {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

.shop-service img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.shop-service .shop-service-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: An absolutely-positioned child of a flex container is *supposed* to be out-of-flow. That's what absolute positioning does. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to meet the problem with flexbox and absolute position in IE.

A more recommended method is to use **transform: translate()** property.

You could combine Flexbox and transform: translate, as the latter does not impact the former.

I've made a sample on my side, and maybe you could refer to.

HTML.

```
    <div class="container shop-service">
    <img class="img-container" src="Images/test7.jpg" />
    <div class="shop-service-content">
        <div class="shop-service-img">
            <img alt="ecommerce" src="Images/test6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <h2>E-commerce</h2>
        <p class="col-md-12">
            Poderá fazer os seus pedidos a qualquer hora do dia, 365 días por ano, de forma
            segura, ágil e confidencial.
        </p> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Comprar agora</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS.

```
   .shop-service {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 35px;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
        position: relative;
    }

        .shop-service .shop-service-content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 400px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }

        .shop-service img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
```

Result screenshot:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CgzH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a declaration of top:0; to your `.shop-service .shop-service-content` class.

Comment: Thanks @Ash Loudon, I tried it.  The div gets into the top of the image but it won't centered the div neither vertically nor horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a height for the parent container `.shop-service`